# Crystal not prompting for parameter

Tags: stored-procedures, crystal-reports

i am working on crystal reports 11. Just added a stored proc with 2 parameters. but refreshing the report does not prompt for new parameters.

Any suggestions.

Thanks
Amrita

Comment: Whey you say you tried "refreshing the report", does that mean you reloaded the report, you tried `Database > Verify Database`, or something else?

Answer (score 2):

1. Did you define your parameter in the Parameter Fields? You didn't specifically say so.
   [image]
2. If your parameter isn't actually in use, you won't be prompted for a value.  i.e. If you drag & drop the parameter onto the design view and refresh, then it should prompt you for a value.

Comment: thanks for the response. basically its sending values for all the parameters as null by default to the database. I have tried "verify database" and "show sql query" . i do not want to create new parameter as these already exist in database SP. The parameters are in use.

Comment: @user192319 did you set the parameters to use null? i know that there is an option when you created the report to make it null.